# Converting Java button into VF button

Tags: apex

I have a Java button, and I am trying to convert it into a VF button, For the purpose I use a standard controller with an extension, but I am hitting a wall, and was hoping if anyone could give direction.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}

var message = sforce.apex.execute("GiftServices","approveGift",
{giftID:'{!Gift__c.Id}'});
```

So far this is what I have written for my controller class:

```
public class GiftApproveCon{  
        private Gift__c gift;
    public GiftApproveCon(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        this.gift = (Gift__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }
    public pageReference approveGift(){ 
        return Page.GiftLinking;
       //return null;
    }  
}
```

Hi, Here is my VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Gift__c" extensions="GiftApproveCon" action="{!approveGift}" > 
    Sample Page 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: where is your visualforce and button click event code?

Comment: Hi, Here is my VF page:
apex:page standardController="Gift__c" extensions="GiftApproveCon" action="{!approveGift}" >
    Sample Page   
</apex:page>

Comment: I have suggest you to go some visualforce trailhead and do some practice

Comment: JavaScript, not Java.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few questions to be answered like:

1. You cannot redirect back to the same page or it will perform the action again, and again, in an endless loop
2. You will need to add proper navigation and error handling
3. This is not a complete list of questions

but as a start, here is an example that redirects back to the calling record

```
public class GiftApproveCon{  
    private Gift__c gift;
    public GiftApproveCon(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        this.gift = (Gift__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }
    public pageReference approveGift(){ 
       if(gift.Id == null) {...; return null;} //Add appropriate page message
       //Do approval
       GiftServices.approveGift(gift.Id); //not sure what it returns but you will need to handle the return value and any errors that could be thrown
       return New PageReference('/' + gift.Id); //Go back to calling record

    }  
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Gift__c" extensions="GiftApproveCon" action="{!approveGift}" > 
    <apex:pageMessages/>
    <!-- Need to add a block here in case of an error to provide a button to go back-->
</apex:page>
```

Again, all the above is basic and meant as a starting point. it is not a complete well thought out implementation.